# Gatling version 2.2.5 install

Tags: yum, gatling

Where can I find rpm, tar or zip for gatling 2.2.5 for download.
Any link that I try points me to the download page of gatling community which has only the latest 3.0.1.1 version of gatling for download.

So far I have tried:

1. https://gatling.io/category/new-release/
2. http://continualintegration.com/miscellaneous-articles/how-do-you-install-gatling-on-a-centosrhelfedora-server
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x/151690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it from here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/gatling/highcharts/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle/2.2.5/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5-bundle.zip